# ... and good company to be in

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "and good company to be in" here?

Context:

It is as if artists were rogue mutations in the body politic, sniffing the wind, open to new ideas, makers of new constructs and constructions, sometimes derided for their lack of conformity, but ahead of their time, leading the way in adapting to new conditions and therefore supreme survivors and good company to be in.

Answer (score 2):

Its meaning here is ambiguous.  It can be taken to mean it's good to be an artist (and so, be counted among their company).  It can also be taken to mean artists are good company to have (as in, it's good to hang out with them).

Answer (score 0):

It means:

Artists think outside the box, and are a bit weird, but all told, you could do worse than to spend your time around artists.  Living with artists, or being an artist, is a good place to be.  It's nothing to be ashamed of, even if you have a few fleas and bedbugs in your loft.